# Intersection of images of balls

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f: M \rightarrow M$ be continuous. For every intrger $n\geq0$, let $f^{n}: M \rightarrow M$ be defined such that $f^{0}=i d$ and $f^{n+1}=f \circ f^{n}$. Supose that for some $a \in M$, $m \neq n \Rightarrow f^{m}(a) \neq f^{n}(a)$. Prove that for all $p \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist a ball $B(a;r)$, $r>0$, such that $$1\leq i \neq j \leq p \Rightarrow f^{i}(B(a;r)) \cap f^{j}(B(a;r))=\varnothing.$$

$B(a;r) = \{x: d(x,a)<r\}$.

My attempt was to to suppose that $f^{i}(B) \cap f^{j}(B)\neq\varnothing$ and then come up with some $x \in M$ such that $f^{m}(x) = f^{n}(x)$, but it didn't work and now I don't know what to do.

Please, any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for a contradiction that there exists $p\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $r>0$, whenever $1\leq i\neq j\leq p$, one has $f^{i}(B(a,r))\cap f^{j}(B(a,r))\neq\emptyset$.

Let $\epsilon=d\left(f^{i}(a),f^{j}(a)\right)/2>0$. By the continuity of $f$, and hence the continuity of $f^{i}$ and $f^{j}$, there exists $\delta_{1},\delta_{2}>0$ such that whenever $m,m'\in M$, satisfying $d\left(m,a\right)<\delta_{1}$ then $d\left(f(m),f(a)\right)<\epsilon$ and similarly, if $d\left(m',a\right)<\delta_{2}$ then $d\left(f(m'),f(a)\right)<\epsilon$. Let $\delta=(1/2)\min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$. Then there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1/4n<\delta$. By assumption, we can find
\begin{equation*}
z_{n}\in f^{i}(B(a,1/4n))\cap f^{j}(B(a,1/4n)).
\end{equation*}
Let $z_{n}=f^{i}(a_{n})=f^{j}(a_{n}')$ for some $a_{n},a_{n}'\in B(a,1/4n)$.

By assumption also, $f^{i}(a)\neq f^{j}(a)$ since $i\neq j$. Then
\begin{equation*}
d\left(f^{i}(a),f^{j}(a)\right)\leq d\left(f^{i}(a),f^{i}(a_{n})\right)+d\left(f^{i}(a),f^{i}(a_{n}')\right)<\epsilon+\epsilon=d\left(f^{i}(a),f^{j}(a)\right).
\end{equation*}
which is a contradiction.